# Передать данные из Битрикс24 в Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Нужно Передать данные из Битрикс24 в Power BI напрямую. В power bi использую power query.
Появляется ошибка в переменной NumberOfRecord: Expression.Error: Не удается применить доступ к полям в типе List. Сведения:
Value=[List]
Key=get_1

В чем может быть проблема?

```
let
GetString=(k,x)=>
let
 QueryCmd="cmd[get_"&Number.ToText(x)&"]",
 QueryFilter=Number.ToText((k-1)*2500+(x-1)*50),
 QueryString = "crm.deal.list?start="&QueryFilter,
 QueryStringURI=Uri.EscapeDataString(QueryCmd)&"="&Uri.EscapeDataString(QueryString)

in
 QueryStringURI,

 GetRecord=(k,NumberOfRecord,b24Site, b24WebhookKey)=>
let

 URLStringEach=List.Generate(
 ()=>1,
 (x)=>x<=Number.RoundUp(NumberOfRecord/50),
 (x)=>x+1,
 (x)=>GetString(k,x)
 ),

 URLString=Text.Combine(URLStringEach,"&"),
 B24Json= Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://"&b24Site&"/rest/1/"&b24WebhookKey&"/batch.json?"&URLString)),

 DealList = B24Json[result][result],
 RecordToTable = Record.ToTable(DealList),
 TableExpandListColumn = Table.ExpandListColumn(RecordToTable,"Value"),
 TableExpandRecordColumn = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(TableExpandListColumn, "Value", {"ID", "TITLE", 
  "TYPE_ID", "STAGE_ID"},{"ID", "TITLE", "TYPE_ID", "STAGE_ID"}),
 TableRemoveColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(TableExpandRecordColumn,{"Name"})
 in
 TableRemoveColumns,

   b24Site="мой сайт",
   b24WebhookKey="мой вебхук",
   B24Json1 = 
   Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://"&b24Site&"/"&b24WebhookKey&"/batch.json?"&GetString(1,1))),
   NumberOfRecord = B24Json1[result][result_total][get_1],
   DealListEach = List.Generate(()=>1,
   (k)=>k<=Number.RoundUp(NumberOfRecord/2500),
   (k)=>k+1,
   (k)=>GetRecord(k,if (NumberOfRecord-(k-1)*2500)>2500 then 2500 else NumberOfRecord-(k- 
    1)*2500,b24Site,b24WebhookKey)
    ),
    TableDeals=Table.Combine(DealListEach)

    in
    TableDeals
```

Answer (score 0):

Мы поступаем по-другому: с помощью коннектора выгружаем данные в БД и уже стандартным коннектором к БД подключаем PowerBI.

Наш коннектор Битрикс24 - [Data Connector](https://www.bitrix24.ru/apps/?app=remark.b24storage), короткое описание:

> Data Connector в реальном времени выгружает данные из Битрикс24 во внешнюю базу данных MySQL.
> Что позволяет работать с данными о клиентах, сделках, делах и т.д. без ограничений restapi, а также формировать отчеты, подключив к базе данных BI-приложения, такие как Microsoft Power BI или Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, Вы указываете:
QueryString = "**crm.deal.list**?start="&QueryFilter,

Проверьте вебхук в Битрикс24. Вероятнее всего, при создании вебхука, Вы не дали доступ к методу.